# Is it okay to hang a heavy object on a kingstud?

Tags: mounting

I'm looking to mount a monitor on a wall near to a window. I've been able to identify some studs in a wall, but it looks like they skipped a stud when they got close to a window. The final stud should be about 6" from the edge of the window, but I can't get a stud finder to pick up anything consistent and the old fashioned wall tap test sounds like it's hollow behind where they stud should be. The window appear to have a proper king and jack or framing stud. Am I good to use the king stud for the monitor mount?

Comment: King and jack studs are just fancy names for studs beside windows and doors.  Might have more problems with watching the monitor beside a window.

Comment: Define "heavy".

Comment: @JACK Not super heavy, but definately more than I'd want to put through plain drywall. Monitor mount lists itself at 5.77 lbs, the monitor lists itself at 9.9 lbs but that's the full package weight including it's default stand which is probably around half of the weight. So a roughly 5 lb monitor hanging off of a 5.77 lb mount. It is important to note that the mount is fully articulating and can hold the monitor up to 15 inches away from the wall, but even then not a huge amount in the grand scheme of wall mounting.

Comment: Your monitor and mount are notably lighter than a 65" TV. While it is _always_ better to mount into solid wood (stud), you will likely be able to get away with putting some screws/bolts into wood and the others into properly rated drywall mounts. After all, a grand total of 15 lbs _max_ isn't really all that heavy and is well within reason for drywall mounts, especially when some of the load is shared by a stud.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The king stud is a full length stud to give rigidity to the jack stud(s). The jack studs are there to support the header over your door or window opening. There is certainly nothing wrong with fastening a monitor to any those studs. Within limits, of course. I mean if you're going to hang The Greatful Dead's sound system from your walls, you might have a problem.

Comment: I agree, especially with the Greatful Dead sound system. Just make sure you screw into the center of either the king or jack but not the center of the king/jack

Comment: Definitely. Especially if using bulky lag screws. I've seen them split a stud in twain.